# Java Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java

I have created one html file under dynamic project. I made that html file as Welcome file under web.xml.

Later I have deleted the html file and entire project from the disk. Now when I have created the same project again with the same name without creating any html file, still I am getting the same old welcome file. I have not created any html file under my new project and have not configured the welcome file under Web.xml.

Please advice.

Comment: First of all tell us which IDE do you use?

Comment: if you are using eclipse you need to clean the project in order to remove old cache. Go to `Project -> Clean`

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0. I have cleaned my project but it doesn't work.

Comment: either delete all data regarding that project from workspace **manually** or switch workspace to some other location

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project location in "Windows Explorer" and delete the entire project. Restart the eclipse and you are done.

It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

- goto tomcat(or other webservice) folder delete this project files in webapps folder
- delete all files in work/Catalina folder
- clean the project
- remove and redeploy this project

maybe it works